# Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource

Tags: angular-material, angular9

I'm trying to implement **Angular Material** table using Angular 9 but I'm getting the following error:

```
Provided data source did not match an array, Observable, or DataSource
```

Can anybody help me understand what is causing the error here?

```js
const ELEMENT_DATA: Pizza[] = [
  {id:1,description:'Muzza',small:300,big:350,tolde:450},
  {id:2,description:'Fug',small:300,big:350,tolde:450},
  {id:3,description:'Pal',small:300,big:350,tolde:450}
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pizzas',
  templateUrl: './pizzas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pizzas.component.css']
})
export class PizzasComponent implements OnInit {

  pizzas=ELEMENT_DATA;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Variedad'];
}
```

```html
  <table mat-table dataSource="pizzas" class="mat-elevation-z4">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Variedad">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descripcion. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pizza"> {{pizza.description}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the component class `PizzasComponent`, `displayedColumns` should contain the property name(s) of the pizzas you want to display in your table.

```
displayedColumns: string[] = ['description'];
```

In the template, you need to define [property binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding-property) for `dataSource`, using angle brackets. Furthermore, `matColumnDef` must match an entry from `displayedColumns`.

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="pizzas" class="mat-elevation-z4">

  <ng-container matColumnDef="description">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Descripcion. </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let pizza"> {{pizza.description}} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Please have a look at this [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzywhf?file=src/app/table-basic-example.html)

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing the square brackets on the html:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="pizzas" class="mat-elevation-z4">
```

This means that there wasn't interpolation between the variable that was in the ts and the one that takes on the html.